# How to get all elements that contain a number from a list in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following list

```
['0 1 2', '1 2 1', '2 3 2', '3 4 1', '4 5 2', '5 0 1', '0 2 3', '0 3 2', '0 4 3', '1 3 3', '1 4 1', '1 5 3', '2 4 3', '2 5 2', '3 5 2']
```

I want to get all elements that contain '0'.

How would I do that? I am a beginner in Python and have been stuck on this problem for days.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

You could use list comprehension to iterate through each element in the list and check if that element contains '0'. If so, include that element.

```
nums = ['0 1 2', '1 2 1', '2 3 2', '3 4 1', '4 5 2', '5 0 1', '0 2 3', '0 3 2', '0 4 3', '1 3 3', '1 4 1', '1 5 3', '2 4 3', '2 5 2', '3 5 2']
has_zero = [num for num in nums if '0' in num]
print(has_zero)
```

Output:

```
['0 1 2', '5 0 1', '0 2 3', '0 3 2', '0 4 3']
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
list2 = []
for element in list1:
  if "0" in element:
    list2.append(element)
```

this should work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter`:

```
>>> l = ['0 1 2', '1 2 1', '2 3 2', '3 4 1', '4 5 2', ...]
>>> list(filter(lambda x: '0' in x, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = ['0 1 2', '1 2 1', '2 3 2', '3 4 1', '4 5 2', '5 0 1', '0 2 3', '0 3 2', '0 4 3', '1 3 3', '1 4 1', '1 5 3',
            '2 4 3', '2 5 2', '3 5 2']

    print([x for x in data if '0' in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
myList= ['0 1 2', '1 2 1', '2 3 2', '3 4 1', '4 5 2', '5 0 1', '0 2 3', '0 3 2', '0 4 3', '1 3 3', '1 4 1', '1 5 3',
        '2 4 3', '2 5 2', '3 5 2']
resultList = []
for item in myList:
    if "0" in item:
        resultList.append(item)
```

If you ask that how this works, simply it loops through list item and checks if the "0" is in the item or not and if it is the item will be added to result list.

Answer (score 0):

Already given options are better, but as understandable as possible for a beginner you can try:

```
myList = ['0 1 2', '1 2 1', '2 3 2', '3 4 1', '4 5 2', '5 0 1', '0 2 3', '0 3 2', '0 4 
3', '1 3 3', '1 4 1', '1 5 3', '2 4 3', '2 5 2', '3 5 2']
elementsContainingZero = []
for element in list:
    splitElement = element.split()
    for number in splitElement:
        if number == '0':
            elementsContainingZero.append(element)

 print(elementsContainingZero)
```

Comment: you don't need to split the element , just by using `in` one can check if the value exist in that element or not, by using this way you are incresing the complexity of problem